# How to generate multiple arrays containing elements from another array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Using just Ruby I am trying to

- Generate an array of random numbers
- Create a new 2 dimensional array containing x amount of arrays filled with x amount of samples from the original number list.

This is what I have...

```
a = 1000.times.map{rand(100)}.to_a
b = 5.times.map{a.sample}
#=> [3, 96, 23, 45, 41]
```

I basically want to be able to generate what I did in b, x amount of times.

Is this possible?

Thank you for the comments everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one-liner to do what you want.

```
3.times.map {2.times.map {rand 1000} }
#=> [[267, 476], [109, 950], [345, 137]]
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your definition of b in another map:

```
a = 1000.times.map{rand(100)} # to_a is unnecessary here, map returns an array
b = 5.times.map{5.times.map{a.sample}}
```

Comment: Andrew, thank you for the comment you left on my answer, which I subsequently deleted. Note only were you correct that the answer was incorrect if the OP's array `a` were used elsewhere in the program, but it was just plain wrong. If, for example, the first array contained 1,000 `1`'s (unlikely as that may be), `b` would always have nothing but `1`'s, whereas I was just generating random values within the originally-specified interval.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Rails installed at the moment, so here's a pure Ruby solution.

```
a = (0..1000).to_a.map! { rand(100) }
x = 2
b =  (0..x).to_a.map! { a.sample(x) }
# [[83, 73], [55, 93], [57, 18]]
```